# Ruby Mocha. List an objects expectations

Tags: ruby, mocking, expectations

With Mocha, is there a way to list current expectations on an object? e.g.

```
  x = Object.new
  x.expects( :foo )
  # something like: puts x.expectations
```

Sorry if this is a really obvious one.

Comment: is there any reason for doing that?

Comment: When writing tests, i'd like to be able to see what expectations have been created as a result of various mocha methods. Just for debugging really.

Comment: I can see why we shouldn't meddle with the expectations, i'd just like to be able to inspect them for debugging.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: Mocha::Mockery.instance.stubba.stubba_methods which returns an array, which stores the all the stubs of all the classes.

Comment: How to distinguish expectations from stubs?

Comment: I figured out but it is very ugly. So I guess a no go for anything important. For mocha 2.1.0 stubs are `Mocha::Mockery.instance.mocks.first.__expectations__.to_a.first.instance_variable_get(:@cardinality).allowed_any_number_of_times?`